# Can I level to 60 as prefered if I buy shadow of revan expansion?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Simple question, I will be going back to preferred status tomorrow, but I would like to continue the game to level 60.

If I buy the shadow of revan expansion, will I be able to play the hutt cartel and new expansion without being subscribed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, if you have bought the expansion you can level trough level 60 without being a subscriber.

If you pre-ordered the expansion before 2 November, 2014 you got 7 days of early access.

Right now ROTHC is available when you have a subscription.

If you pre-ordered Shadow of Revan before it was released, and you were a subscriber, you got a 12x XP boost on your class missions until December 2014.

See the official [Shadow of Revan](http://www.swtor.com/shadow-of-revan?intcmp=sor_bwa-mkt-t-us-hp-156) page for more information.